# bootstrap validation error showing before any text entered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I using bootstrap with MVC and Im trying to use validation but I get a strange problem.  When I open up the form with the bootstrap stying, The text inputs are already outlined in red and the validation message is showing BEFORE ive actually typed anything into the textbox, can anyone tell me how to avoid this ? heres the html

```html
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-error">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Last Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, "You must include a last name.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share the Get Action method, I think you are passing the Model name in Get Action Method eg  _public ActionResult Index(ModelName obj)_ , use simple _public ActionResult Index()_

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, "You must include a last name.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

In this you are already give Error Message ="You must include a last name."..but its should message come from ***data annotation model validation***.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must include a last name.")]
public string LastName{ get; set; }


 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

In ValidationMessageFor Message should be null. like as above shown in code.

Comment: I had already tried that, but its the bootstrap class which seems to be the problem, as soon as I add 'has-error' the text is displayed in red and the text box has a red border before I submit the form